# Reading Outlook mail in R

Tags: r, tm

I have tried some approaches to read outlook mail via MongoDb in R(BSON) but not succeeded because of BSON of PST is not readable in R(#I used readBin()) then I tried directly to Read it in R via **tm.plugin.mail** but getting an error:-

```
 library(tm.plugin.mail)
 convert_mbox_eml("C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Documents\\Outlook Files\\Outlook Data File - Abc.pst","C:\\tm")
 Warning message:
 In readLines(mbox) :
 incomplete final line found on 'C:\Users\Kuldeep\Documents\Outlook Files\Outlook Data File - Ashish.pst'
```

This library is only **plugin** for tm or can we read out mails from PST in R,Is their any approach to read out mails in R,Please help me out as fast as possible.thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

help(convert_mbox_eml) says:

```
Convert E-Mails From mbox Format To eml Format
```

You don't have mbox format. You have Outlook PST format. You might be able to export from Outlook in mbox format. Or you might find a utility to do the conversion. But nothing in that package is going to help you.

Comment: thanks,can you say me any utility to do the conversion or Is their any better way to read out pst in R ?

Comment: Suggest you search for conversion utilities, or ask on a suitable forum (Stack Overflow isnt the place).